# how to reload or refresh a view in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

i have a uitableviewcontroller
here is the .h file code

```
@interface addToFavourites : UITableViewController {

}

@end
```

and here is the .m file code

```
#import "addToFavourites.h"


@implementation addToFavourites

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
    }
    return self;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // Configure the cell

    return cell;
}

@end
```

and in another class i am showing this view using this code

```
addToFavouritesobj = [[addToFavourites alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:addToFavouritesobj animated:YES];
```

how do i call reload method of this `uitableviewcontroller` class?

there is no need of declaring tableview because this view automatically genrating a table

i am very confused how to reload the table?

Comment: A minor nitpick about your code: In Objective-C, class names generally begin with an uppercase letter. Your addToFavorites class should be AddToFavorites, AddToFavoritesController, etc. I would use AddFavoriteController. Using Objective-C naming conventions will make it easier for others to help you. For example, I was thrown off that when I saw [addToFavorites alloc] and was about to post telling  you that alloc is a class method and you shouldn't be calling it on an instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`addToFavouritesobj.tableView` will give you access to the `UITableView` object.

```
[addToFavouritesobj.tableView reloadData]
```

---

BTW: class names should start with capital letter. A better name for your class would be `AddToFavouritesController`.

Comment: Is reloadData a method implemented elsewhere?

Comment: reloadData is a method of UITableView, so it's available everywhere where you can get to that object.